# Efficent way to Query a DB and write to text file - Large Recordset

Tags: vb.net

I have a SQL query that returns a recordset with between 2 and 5 million records and I need to write that to a .csv file.

I wrote the following procedure and I'm curious to see if there is a better / more efficient way to do this.

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection()
...
Sub DBExecuteQueryWriteToFile(ByVal SQLCommand As String, ByVal FileName As String, Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",")

    Dim cmd = New OracleCommand(SQLCommand, conn)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim CountRow As Integer = 0

    If File.Exists(FileName) Then
        File.Delete(FileName)
    End If

    Using FileObject As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Using MStream As New MemoryStream()
            Using StreamWriterObj As New StreamWriter(MStream)
                Using Reader As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim FieldCount As Integer = Reader.FieldCount - 1

                    Do While Reader.Read()
                        sb.Append(Reader.Item(0))
                        For i = 1 To FieldCount
                            sb.Append(Delimiter)
                            sb.Append(Reader.Item(i))
                        Next
                        sb.Append(vbCrLf)

                        'Write every 25000 rows of data to the file from the buffer
                        If x = 25000 Then
                            StreamWriterObj.Write(sb.ToString().ToCharArray())
                            MStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                            MStream.WriteTo(FileObject)
                            sb = New StringBuilder()
                            CountRow = CountRow + x
                            x = 0
                        End If
                        x = x + 1
                    Loop

                    'Write any remaining data from the buffer to the file
                    StreamWriterObj.Write(sb.ToString().ToCharArray())
                    MStream.WriteTo(FileObject)

                    Reader.Close()
                    StreamWriterObj.Close()
                    MStream.Close()
                    FileObject.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Any and all comments and help are geatly appreciated and, also, even though this is written in VB, I'm equally as comfortable with C# solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the code greatly without loosing any performance, more likely gaining instead.

There is no need to use `StringBuilder` - you can write directly to the `StreamWriter` - it will be faster since there will be no need of copy the whole data twice.

Next, there is no need to use `MemoryStream` - you are using it to buffer data before writing it to the disk. The same can be achieved by specifying the buffer size when creating `FileStream`. You should play around with the buffer size to see what is fastest on your environment - usually 4KB is used, in the sample below it is 1MB, but you have to try it on your hardware.

You should also play around with the [options how to open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `FileStream`. You should try what impact `Asynchronous` and `WriteThrough` has on your solution.

Of course, as the other answer proposed, separating reading from database and writing to the file in two threads might work as well. Try and measure three separate scenarios - just reading from the database (measure separately the query (`ExecuteReader()` and first `Read()` and then reading the other rows - because it might be that most of the time is spending to initially execute the query, not to iterate through the data), just writing to the file (dummy data) and then combined. This way you will see if there is actual reason to put the two operations in parallel.

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection()
...
Sub DBExecuteQueryWriteToFile(ByVal SQLCommand As String, ByVal FileName As String, Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",")

    Dim cmd = New OracleCommand(SQLCommand, conn)
    Dim bufferSize = 1024*1024; // 1Mb

    If File.Exists(FileName) Then
        File.Delete(FileName)
    End If

    Using FileObject As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize)
    Using StreamWriterObj As New StreamWriter(FileObject)
    Using Reader As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim FieldCount As Integer = Reader.FieldCount - 1

        Do While Reader.Read()
            StreamWriterObj.Write(Reader.Item(0))
            For i = 1 To FieldCount
                StreamWriterObj.Write(Delimiter)
                StreamWriterObj.Write(Reader.Item(i))
            Next
            StreamWriterObj.WriteLine();
        Loop

    End Using
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

P.S. few other issues in your code:

1. `StringBuilder().ToString().ToCharArray()` - no need to convert to char array.
2. `new StringBuilder()` - instead of reusing the memory already allocated to the existing builder, you are throwing that away and creating new one.
3. `MStream.Seek()` - you are seeking to the beginning of the stream but are not setting `Length` to 0. So if the second block written there is smaller than first one, junk data will be written to the file.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY AMAZING ANSWER!!! - Thank you **SO MUCH** for taking the time to describe everything and the sample code... Truly, a perfect answer!!! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to break the code that writes to the file out into a separate thread.  This would allow you to read the next 25,000 rows while simultaneously writing the 25,000 rows that you've already retrieved.  There is a caveat here though that you will want to wait until the previous file writing thread finishes before spawning a new file writing thread so you don't mess up the writing of the file.  The performance gains could be minor to significant using this approach depending on the speed of your query, network, CPU and hard drive.  If writing to a file is just as fast as returning the next 25,000 rows, you may not find the performance gains worth the additional work of managing a separate thread depending on the amount of milliseconds it takes to do each task.  Ultimately though, the best speed you will be able to attain is going to be that of which you can write the file without interruption by the data pull.

Comment: Definitely worthwhile looking into and definitely a smart idea I hadn't thought of!! - Thank you!!! +1